# "appointed as" VS "named"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. XYZ was **named** the new Senior Vice President Human Resources for the Group from October 1, 2015.
> 2. XYZ was **appointed as** the new Senior Vice President Human Resources for the Group from October 1, 2015.

I have two question: In the translation dictionay, "named" just means the post is reserved for the guy. So does this mean "named" is different from "appointed as", which mean the gus has actually take the post.

Another, should we choose "named" or "named as"?

Comment: Use a normal *English* dictionary (you're being misled by your "translation dictionay"). To clarify the *potential* difference between the two terms, consider [*George Keyworth resigned after he was **named** as the source of the leak.*](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C2CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&ei=N-0PXOfYAsq5kwXfpr_AAg&q=%22Director+George+Keyworth+resigned+after+he+was+named+as+the+source+of+the+leak%22&oq=%22Director+George+Keyworth+resigned+after+he+was+named+as+the+source+of+the+leak%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31927.31927..33282...0.0..0.118.118.0j1......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71.qLMYpYghaqk)

Comment: Also, it should be "vice president *of* Human Resources"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Named" in this context means his name was released. That normally occurs *after* a person is offered a job role, accepted it, and then that information is released to everybody else.

By way of example, the expression is also sometimes used in connection with crimes - "*the suspect/victim has been named as John Doe*" - and this can sometimes occur quite some time after the person is known to or has been arrested by the police. "Naming" them is the act of making that information known to a wider audience.

A person being "*appointed*" to a job role would normally be considered to occur when that person actually begins working in the role, in which case their appointment could come a while *after* they are named as a successful candidate.

You should use "named as", if you are using it for the purpose I described above, that is to describe the act of releasing the person's name to the public. Without the word "as" it reads as if the person has been given the name of "Senior Vice President", which is of course not a name but a title. If though you mean to describe the act of placing someone into a job role, you should perhaps say they were "appointed", in which case you *wouldn't* need to use "as" (see [this questio](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62720/appointed-as-or-just-appointed)n for an accepted answer to that)

Comment: Yes, very much so.  See for example recent news in which President Trump **named** (nominated) a new chief of staff, only to have that person decline the job.  He's since **named** someone else, and we'll see if he takes up the **appointment**.  However in most contexts like this I think it's fine to use either "named" or "named as".  The sentence would be structured differently if you were talking about someone's name/title, e.g.  *"She was **named** after her grandmother"*